# Using power series, find an indefinite integral of $f(x)=\cos(x^2)$.

Tags: calculus, power-series, indefinite-integrals

I don't really understand this at all. I think you have to use the derivative of $\cos(x^2)$ which is $-2x\sin(x^2)$, and use the power series of $\sin(x)$, but I don't know where I would go from there...

Comment: I expect they mean:  find a power series expression for the indefinite integral.  There isn't anything like a convenient expression in elementary functions.

Answer (score 3):

We know that:

$$cos(x^2)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k \frac{x^{4k}}{(2k)!}$$

Therefore,

$$\int cos(t^2)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k \frac{x^{4k+1}}{(4k+1)(2k)!}$$

There is no closed form of the expression of such an indefinite integral, it's a [Fresnel integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fresnel_integral) if you want to know more about it.